# Update URL onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update my current URL in side my **click()** function

```
var str = window.location; // http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/10001/edit/private/basic
var new_str = str.replace("basic", "a");
alert(new_str);
location.href = new_str;
```

---

I kept getting

[image]

---

Did I do anything I'm not suppose to here ?

Answer (score 3):

You were close.  Your replace statement is changing the url prematurely.

```
var new_str = window.location.href.replace("basic", "a");
alert(new_str);
window.location.href = new_str;
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` is not a string, it just has a string representation. So the `.replace` method you're calling is not the `String` `.replace` method. It's actually [the location replacement method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace), which navigates to a new page without adding a new history entry and returns nothing/`undefined`.

If you convert it to a `String` (or access the equivalent `.href` property) your code will work:

```
var str = String(window.location); // http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/10001/edit/private/basic
var new_str = str.replace("basic", "a");
alert(new_str);
location.href = new_str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the property 'href' from window.location:

```
var str = window.location.href; // << Get href
var new_str = str.replace("basic", "a");
alert(new_str);
location.href = new_str;
```